# JAVA - Write into html files

Tags: java, html

I am looking to write inside an html file using java.

I have my index.html page ready and I would like to use this template and add a name list (with hyperlinks to go to their pages) at a certain place in this page.
Is it possible to use beacons or tags to tell java to write to this exact location in the html file?

I will use this type of java code to write, the array will be a names array btw, but it's in this mind:

```html
String[] labelEquipment = { "thing1", "thing2", "thing3", "thing4",
                "thing5", "thing6", "thing7", "thing8", "thing9",
                "thing10" };
PrintWriter f0 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt"));

        for (String string : labelEquipment) {
            f0.println(string);
        }
        f0.close();
```

Comment: For this kind of behavior, you can use JSP technology to dynamically change the content of the HTML page. Or there are some template engines, you can work on e.g. Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a html file like this :

```
<body>
{{my_placeholder}}
</body>
```

Using java, you can read this file as string and then use `.replace('{{my_placeholder}}',your_content)` to replace the place holder with individual label equipments. The variable `your_content` will have to be group of html tags that will be placed  in your html in place of `my_placeholder`